# Custom response on logging in to Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Need to have custom response for logging in into Spring MVC application.

Current sensible default response to athenticating a user seems to be 302 with "Location:" header pointing to the desired part of application.

What if the web application happens to be a Single Page Application so that it would not need to actually redirect to anywhere?

So far I have managed to play with two filters: One before **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter** and another after **FilterSecurityInterceptor** class in chain.

In code the former is extending **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter** and processes the credentials and store a session attribute, while the latter is looking for that attribute and if present will end up responding with desired response data (later also removing the attribute from session).

Good side of the filter pair so far is that it is possible to write a custom response to a login request. Also new session is properly initialized and we can reuse existing session fixation strategy.

Problems with described two filters approach:

- Redirect will happen back to root of web application ("/"), albeit it is possible to reset the buffer and write a custom data (a simple JSON response) - no success in overriding the redirection;
- Any request done in parallel would get that custom data (care has to be taken that no other request is made to any other path of the application until authenticated;
- When done at filter time, user rights are not yet known. No idea what status code to respond with until credentials have been passed through AuthenticationProvider.
- Bonus Question: What if for some reason also good old username and password filter needs to co-operate?

I can not paste full code to minimal application yet, but so far Spring Security conf has following excrept at a configuration class extending **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .cors()
            .disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .disable()
            .formLogin()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/welcome")
            .hasAuthority(MyAuthenticationProvider.AUTH_WELCOME.getAuthority())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(getMyAuthenticationFilter("/auth/login"), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(getMyResponseFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    private Filter getMyAuthenticationFilter(String loginUrl) {
        return new MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter(loginUrl);
    }

    private Filter getMyResponseFilter() {
        return new MyAuthenticationReplyFilter();
    }
```

And Filters are following:

```
package org.so.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;
import org.so.example.auth.TokenHolder;
import org.so.example.auth.MyAuthenticationToken;

public class MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);

    protected static final String MY_RESPONSE_DATA = "MY_RESPONSE_DATA";

    public MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        LOG.info("Created MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter {}", defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
    }

    public MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter(RequestMatcher requestMatcher) {
        super(requestMatcher);
        LOG.info("Created MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter {}", requestMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOG.info("doFilter");
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        if (!"POST".equals(req.getMethod())) {
            throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("POST only please");
        }

        // TODO authenticate the request and compose data

        // Once here, need to reply with My specific response
        // At moment there is another filter for that (farther in chain for always returning a success with detected user name).
        // however the user has not been authorized to do anything yet.
        // No idea what http status code to respond with.

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        request.getSession().setAttribute(MY_RESPONSE_DATA, sub);

        return new MyAuthenticationToken(sub, parsedToken);
    }
}
```

````
package org.so.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

/**
 * This filter is meant to be last in chain to provide special kind of authentication response
 */
public class MyAuthenticationReplyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAuthenticationReplyFilter.class);

    public MyAuthenticationReplyFilter() {
        LOG.info("Constructing special reply filter");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOG.info("doFilter");
        if (res.isCommitted()) {
            LOG.warn("How come response is already committed at filter time?");
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            String userName = (String) request
                .getSession()
                .getAttribute(MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter.MY_RESPONSE_DATA);
            if (userName != null) {
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
                response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                response.setStatus(200);
                response.resetBuffer();
                //TODO sanitize data set by authentication processing filter
                response.getWriter().write("{\"great\" : \"success\", \"sub\": \"" + userName + "\"}");
                LOG.info("Responded with http 200 and some json instead of redirection");
                request.getSession().removeAttribute(MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter.MY_RESPONSE_DATA);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: How is the login provided? By a form or HTTP-Basic or OAuth? If e.g. you have a login page then you send a HTTP Get for recieving this page and a HTTP POST for sending the credentials. But in the response of the POST request you can direct to any page you want.

Comment: What confuses me is that there might be lots of initial GET requests. The login button could open dialog without any URL change using modern javascript.Take for example news page that might require logging in to enable commenting. Single POST will be done at one point and no redirection is expected at all. Wouldn't http status and new cookie alone suffice? Why reload rest of data at browser at all:?
It really seems like Spring MVC is not ment for Single Page Applications.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if this works but maybe you can try to use the login POST as AJAX-Request. Then you don't have the problem of redirection and you can dynamically change only the content you want  for a logged in user.

Comment: Thank you very much! At moment things seem better when submitting the login data using AJAX-Request instead!

Comment: But be aware of security. Maybe you must add encryption yourself. And don't forget to enable CSRF-Protetion.